# Emulate "Go to Dekstop/Home/etc." behavior in OS X via AppleScript

Tags: macos, finder, applescript

OS X has build in support for going to certain Folders (Home, Utilities, Desktop, etc.) via a Shortcut.

I wanted to emulate this behavior for the the Downloads Folder. The only thing that is missing the script below is that it won’t succeed when no window is opened in the Finder (see Error message).

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set target of Finder window 1 to folder "Downloads" of folder "username" of disk "Macintosh HD"
end tell
```

Error message:

> error "Finder got an error: Can’t set
>   Finder window 1 to folder
>   \"Downloads\" of folder \"username\"
>   of disk \"Macintosh HD\"." number
>   -10006 from Finder window 1

It great if you know about some kind of 'if-compliement' that triggers opening the Downloads Folder in case there is no window 1 open in the Finder. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply use an `open` statement as follows, exploiting the fact that the Finder already knows what `home` means:

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    open folder "Downloads" of home
end tell
```

which will create a new window showing the Downloads folder or bring any window currently showing the Downloads folder to the front.

Answer (score 1):

The *Go* menu items open a new window if none is open yet. So to get the same behavior:

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    if (count of windows) is equal to 0 then
        open folder "Macinthosh HD:Users:yourname:Downloads"
    else
        set target of (first window whose index is equal to 1) to folder "Macinthosh HD:Users:yourname:Downloads"
    end if
end tell
```

---

This doesn't work if you use *FileVault* though. You can always use a path relative to your home folder using

```
folder "Downloads" of home
```

as @Asmus suggested.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, it was very useful to understand the if/else part. I guess this will be very useful in some other scripts that I try to setup now.

Answer (score 1):

`set target` is pretty annoying to use in column view though. It includes every column starting from the root, even if some of the containing folders were in the sidebar.

I use something like this myself:

```
tell app "Finder"
    activate
    set p to path to desktop
    close every window
    open folder p
    set w to window 1
    set toolbar visible of w to false
    set current view of w to column view
    set bounds of w to {0, 22, 960, 589}
end tell
```

And for example <kbd>⌥A</kbd> opens /Applications.

It doesn't really *emulate* those default shortcuts, but there are a few advantages:

- You can use global shortcuts, a bit like with Quicksilver triggers
- It restores the default bounds (like Finder Minder)
- You can make sure that the window opens with your preferred view options
- IMO it's better to have just a single Finder window open at a time, so this sort of enforces it

Comment: Wow! That’s also a very nice script. Often I need several windows open when I'm sorting out stuff. This script will enables me to easily clean up the mess I’ve made with all that open finder windows and focus on one window - this will sure come in handy. Thank you l-ri!